# How to divide dataset by conditions in R

Tags: r, least-squares

I'd like to get some general rule how to deal with this approach. I've got big data but below is representative example of it:

```
set.seed(2019)

myFun <- function(n = 50) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}
names = myFun()
group = round(runif(50, 0, 4))
condit = ifelse(round(runif(50, 0, 1.2)) > 0, "TRUE", "FALSE")
edf <- data.frame(names, group, condit, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

```
> head(edf)
       names group condit
1 NPWZX7229I     1  FALSE
2 FTANS2931N     0   TRUE
3 XUUGJ9010I     1  FALSE
4 THMIQ8703O     2   TRUE
5 NRLLS3573V     1   TRUE
6 LCETQ1320W     0  FALSE
```

The problem is to divide (cluster) this data on N groups with constraints:

say N = 5,

each group needs to have possibly the same amount of TRUE and FALSE values (as close to it as possible while there's not 50% rate)

each group needs to have possibly the same amount of values from `group` column.

So for example, for N=5, we'd take manually:

```
names   group   condit
wrd0        0     TRUE
wrd1        0     TRUE
wrd2        1     TRUE
wrd3        1    FALSE
wrd4        2    FALSE
wrd5        2    FALSE
wrd6        3     TRUE
wrd7        3    FALSE
wrd8        4    FALSE
wrd9        4     TRUE
```

It's ideal, but how to replicate this automatically for other groups? Is it some library (for sure it is) but I don't know what to use. Cluster? Or maybe some method of the least squares? What library to use? Thanks.

The suggestion of splitting it randomly makes some sense and result:

```
split(edf, sample(1:N, nrow(df), replace=T))
```

But I know this could be better fit.

Comment: Given that your data is big wouldn't a random sample of rows achieve what you are looking for?

Comment: Probably not, because it's skewed. Those values are not equally distributed like in the example.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work for `split`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found an answer. It's very simple and probably gives the best possible fit. It's iterative stuff.

```
devtools::install_github("m-Py/minDiff")

library(minDiff)

xdf <- create_groups(edf, criteria_scale = c("group"), 
                     criteria_nominal = c("condit"), sets_n = 5, repetitions = 5000)
```

You can view it's quite there - depending on how much data is skewed or asymmetric it gives worse or better feeling.

View by:
`xdf[order(xdf$newSet, xdf$condit, xdf$group),]`

Uff...

Answer (score 0):

**Lazy Way**

Here is a `tidyverse` way to do it via random sampling.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

edf %>%
  split(.$group) %>%
  map(~ sample_n(., size = 5, replace = T)) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

**Custom Way**

Here is a **flexible way** that you can extend with your own conditionals. Here I ensured that all the original samples with fewer than 5 iterations are guaranteed to be included. How you want to handle the skewing sampling can be up to you.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

desired_sample_size = 5

conditional_sampling <- function(l){

    r = list(
      l %>% map(
                ~ sample_n(., 
                size = ifelse(nrow(.) < desired_sample_size, nrow(.), desired_sample_size), 
                replace = F)),
      l %>% map_if(~ desired_sample_size - nrow(.) > 0, 
                   ~ sample_n(., 
                              size = desired_sample_size - nrow(.), 
                              replace = T))
    )

    return(combine(r))
}

edf %>%
  split(.$group) %>%
  conditional_sampling() %>%
  bind_rows()
```